# Passing the result of a function to server.js in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie in Node JS and trying to get my head around functional programming.
I have the following code in a file called findinfo.js and I'm trying to pass the result to the main server.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const values = ["yes", "no", "?", "unknown", "partial"];
var cInfo = [];

function getFile (cb) {
    fs.readFile('./scripts/blahblah.json', 'utf-8', function (err, jfile) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error (err);
        }
        console.log("Function is executing...")
        JSON.parse(jfile);
        console.log('Parsing file done');
        cb(jfile);
    });
}
```

Then I'm trying to call this function from server.js,

```
var findinfo = require('./findinfo');
console.log(getFile());
```

which as expected crashes the program.

So what changes should I make in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export `getFile` so it can be imported using `require`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const values = ["yes", "no", "?", "unknown", "partial"];
var cInfo = [];

function getFile (cb) {
    fs.readFile('./scripts/blahblah.json', 'utf-8', function (err, jfile) {
        if (err) {
            // throw new Error (err); // don't throw inside async callback
            return cb(err);
        }
        console.log("Function is executing...")
        JSON.parse(jfile);
        console.log('Parsing file done');
        cb(null, jfile);
    });
}

module.exports = getFile;
```

**server.js**

```
var getFile = require('./findinfo');

getFile(function(err, file) {
   console.log(err, file);
});
```

since `getFile` is an asynchronous function, you have to wait until it finishes, when `cb` is called, to `console.log` the result.

And using `throw` in a asynchronous callback is not recommended, since it will crash the server, it's recommended to pass the error to the callback.

You should take a look at this question, so you learn more about how to handle asynchronous code.

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)